# How can I tell if a column in my sqlite3 RoR database has a database index on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

How can I tell if a column in my sqlite3 database has a database index on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.schema](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7)

Answer (score 0):

Look up the table definition in the schema, or the CREATE TAbLE statement in your DB creation script.